# "optional" generator inside a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, es6-promise

Is it possible to have generators inside a switch statement ? 
As in the function may not always passback a generator ?

In code:

```
function* getWebsite ($) {
  const contents = $('.selector-blah');
  if (contents) {
    const resp = yield http.getHTML({ url: contents.href });
    return resp.finalUrl;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

const selectorMappings = {
  name: '#name',
  starRating: getStarRating, // normal function
  website: getWebsite // generator function
}

yield processSelectors($, data, selectorMappings);
// <code> here is excuting before yield is complete above.
```

processSelectors Module:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const sanitizeText = require('./sanitizeText');

module.exports = function* processSelectors ($, data, selectors = {}, route = '') {
  const keys = Object.keys(selectors);
  for (let key of keys) {
    let path = route ? route + '.' + key : key;
    switch (selectors[key].constructor.name) {
      case 'String':
        _.set(data, path, sanitizeText($(selectors[key]).first().text()));
        break;
      case 'Function':
        _.set(data, path, selectors[key]($));
        break;
      case 'GeneratorFunction':
        var result = yield selectors[key]($);
        _.set(data, path, result);
        break;
      case 'Object':
        _.set(data, path, {});
        processSelectors($, data, selectors[key], path);
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

I did have the switch inside a forEach but moved out to avoid nested functions but didn't help, also tried using co and co.wrap too, along with Promise's.

Comment: A function either is a generator or it's not. It shouldn't (can't) decide at runtime what it wants to be. How will the *caller* know what it decided to be?

Comment: You can write a generator function that never yields, but you should not write a function that only sometimes returns a generator.

Comment: Where is that `yield processSelectors($, data, selectorMappings);` called?

Comment: It's called in another function that is a generator, that called via co. That all works fine.

I guess I could make it always return  generator, I did already try by exporting a co.wrap function.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by making whole thing a generator:

```
yield processSelectors($, data, selectorMappings);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                       MODULE                       //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const _ = require('lodash');
const sanitizeText = require('./sanitizeText');

module.exports = function* processSelectors ($, data, selectors = {}, route = '') {
  const keys = Object.keys(selectors);
  for (let key of keys) {
    let path = route ? route + '.' + key : key;
    switch (selectors[key].constructor.name) {
      case 'String':
        _.set(data, path, sanitizeText($(selectors[key]).first().text()));
        break;
      case 'Function':
        _.set(data, path, selectors[key]($));
        break;
      case 'GeneratorFunction':
        _.set(data, path, yield selectors[key]($));
        break;
      case 'Object':
        _.set(data, path, {});
        processSelectors($, data, selectors[key], path);
        break;
    }
  }
};
```